# Counting mode occurrences for all columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below.

dataframe1 =

```
In  AA   BB  CC
0   10   1   0
1   11   2   3
2   10   6   0
3   9    1   0
4   10   3   1
5   1    2   0
```

now I want to create a dataframe that gives me the count of modes for each column, for column AA the count is 3 for mode 10, for columns CC the count is 4 for mode 0, but for BB there are two modes 1 and 2, so for BB I want the sum of counts for the modes. so for BB the count is 2+2=4, for mode 1 and 2.

Therefore the final dataframe that I want looks like below.

```
Columns  Counts
AA        3
BB        4
CC        4
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare columns with `mode`s and count matches by `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Columns': df.columns,
                   'Val':[df[x].isin(df[x].mode()).sum() for x in df]})
print (df)
  Columns  Val
0      AA    3
1      BB    4
2      CC    4
```

Comment: If I have 1000 rows for each column (say there are 100 columns) and some of the columns have more than 50 modes, then how to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Another slightly more scalable solution using list comprehension:

```
pd.concat([df.eq(x) for _, x in df.mode().iterrows()]).sum()
```

[out]

```
AA    3
BB    4
CC    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

First we get the modes of the columns with [`DataFrame.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)

Then we compare each column to it's modes and use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check the **amount** of modes and `sum` these.

```
modes = df.iloc[:, 1:].mode()
data = {col: df[col].isin(modes[col]).sum() for col in df.iloc[:, 1:].columns}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Counts'])

    Counts
AA       3
BB       4
CC       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Used pyjanitor module to bring in the transform function and return a dataframe:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='In')
 .groupby('variable')
 .agg(numbers=('value','value_counts'))
 .groupby_agg(by='variable',
 #here, it subtracts the max of numbers(for each group) from each 
  number in the group
              agg = lambda x : x - x.max(),
              agg_column_name='numbers',
              new_column_name = 'test'
             )
 .query('test==0')
 .groupby('variable')
 .agg(count=('numbers','sum'))
   )

          count
variable    
AA          3
BB          4
CC          4
```